# Attach File Through PHP Mail

Tags: php, html, email-attachments

I am trying to get a custom contact form using PHP mail to have a user attach a photo, that then gets sent to the recipient outlined in the PHP mail code

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
```

The form code is as follows;

```
<form action="register-mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The PHP mail code is as follows;

```
<?php $file = $_FILES['file'];
 $formcontent="Email Text Content";
 $recipient = "fake@email.com";
 $subject = "Here is a Photo";
 $mailheader = 'From: Basic Sign-up <fake@email.com>' . "\r\n";
 mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
die();
?>
```

I can't seem to get it to attach the file to the email being sent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

That is not how attachment works. Using the `mail()` for attachments is a little more complex than that. You got to tell `mail()` which part should handle the file attachment and which part is responsible to display the email body by setting up a [**MIME Boundary**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). In other words, the code should be divided into 2 parts:

- A section to handle the message being sent in body
- A section to handle file uploading

A detailed tutorial is here

[**PHP EMAIL WITH ATTACHMENT**](http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-mail/php-send-email-upload-form-attachment-file/)

However, I would suggest you to use a very handy tool called PHPMailer to do the same task. It simplifies the process and lets the class handle all the legwork.

[**PHPMailer**](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)