# Include multiple attachment by mail PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

First of all, I know there are many library out there to do what I want to do, mainly PHPMailer and SwiftMailer.
For some reason, those two are not working with my server.

So here I am doing it from scratch.

I've found this code on the PHP documentation which is working quite fine, I would like to know how to tweak the code in order to send multiple files instead of one.

Here the code:

```
<?php
echo date("H:i:s");
echo mail::sendMail("to@domain.com", "Test Attach ".  date("H:i:s"), "Contenu du mail <a href=3D'domain.com'>domain.com</a>", __FILE__, "xx@domain.com",'' , true);
?>

source :

<?php

class mail {

    public static function prepareAttachment($path) {
        $rn = "\r\n";

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $ftype = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
            $file = fopen($path, "r");
            $attachment = fread($file, filesize($path));
            $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment));
            fclose($file);

            $msg = 'Content-Type: \'' . $ftype . '\'; name="' . basename($path) . '"' . $rn;
            $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $rn;
            $msg .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename($path) . '>' . $rn;
//            $msg .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ebf7a33f5a2ffca7_0.1' . $rn;
            $msg .= $rn . $attachment . $rn . $rn;
            return $msg;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function sendMail($to, $subject, $content, $path = '', $cc = '', $bcc = '', $_headers = false) {

        $rn = "\r\n";
        $boundary = md5(rand());
        $boundary_content = md5(rand());

// Headers
        $headers = 'From: Mail System PHP <no-reply@domain.com>' . $rn;
        $headers .= 'Mime-Version: 1.0' . $rn;
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary=' . $boundary . $rn;

        //adresses cc and ci
        if ($cc != '') {
            $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $cc . $rn;
        }
        if ($bcc != '') {
            $headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $cc . $rn;
        }
        $headers .= $rn;

// Message Body
        $msg = $rn . '--' . $boundary . $rn;
        $msg.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;" . $rn;
        $msg.= " boundary=\"$boundary_content\"" . $rn;

//Body Mode text
        $msg.= $rn . "--" . $boundary_content . $rn;
        $msg .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1' . $rn;
        $msg .= strip_tags($content) . $rn;

//Body Mode Html        
        $msg.= $rn . "--" . $boundary_content . $rn;
        $msg .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . $rn;
        $msg .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . $rn;
        if ($_headers) {
            $msg .= $rn . '<img src=3D"cid:template-H.PNG" />' . $rn;
        }
        //equal sign are email special characters. =3D is the = sign
        $msg .= $rn . '<div>' . nl2br(str_replace("=", "=3D", $content)) . '</div>' . $rn;
        if ($_headers) {
            $msg .= $rn . '<img src=3D"cid:template-F.PNG" />' . $rn;
        }
        $msg .= $rn . '--' . $boundary_content . '--' . $rn;

//if attachement
        if ($path != '' && file_exists($path)) {
            $conAttached = self::prepareAttachment($path);
            if ($conAttached !== false) {
                $msg .= $rn . '--' . $boundary . $rn;
                $msg .= $conAttached;
            }
        }

//other attachement : here used on HTML body for picture headers/footers
        if ($_headers) {
            $imgHead = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../modules/notification/ressources/img/template-H.PNG';
            $conAttached = self::prepareAttachment($imgHead);
            if ($conAttached !== false) {
                $msg .= $rn . '--' . $boundary . $rn;
                $msg .= $conAttached;
            }
            $imgFoot = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../modules/notification/ressources/img/template-F.PNG';
            $conAttached = self::prepareAttachment($imgFoot);
            if ($conAttached !== false) {
                $msg .= $rn . '--' . $boundary . $rn;
                $msg .= $conAttached;
            }
        }

// Fin
        $msg .= $rn . '--' . $boundary . '--' . $rn;

// Function mail()
        mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    }

}

?>
```

Where it says: **FILE** that where I've put the file name.
How do I do it so I can put more than one file.

Thank you.

Comment: This is pain, I would stick with the mentioned libraries and try to make them work.

Comment: Try to send yourself a letter with several attachments and see it's source.

Comment: I did, but when there are more than one attachment I don't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `mail()` for attachments is a little more complex than that. You got to tell `mail()` which part should handle the file attachment and which part is responsible to display the email body by setting up a [**MIME Boundary**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). In other words, the code should be divided into 2 parts:

- A section to handle the message being sent in body
- A section to handle file uploading

A detailed tutorial is here

[**PHP EMAIL WITH ATTACHMENT**](http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-mail/php-send-email-upload-form-attachment-file/)

However, I would suggest you to use a very handy tool called PHPMailer to do the same task. It simplifies the process and lets the class handle all the legwork.

[**PHPMailer**](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

**ref** : [Attach File Through PHP Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961969/attach-file-through-php-mail/11962072#11962072)

Comment: The only thing I don't like about PHPMailer is that there are different version for different PHP version, therefore, When I test it on my server it might work but un the client's server it might not.

Comment: sometimes this happens because of different server configuration